# Unable to install excel Node module on MAC OS X 10.10. 5

Tags: node.js

```
$ npm install excel
```

Getting this below error when trying to install Node excel module

```
3 warnings generated.
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libxml/vendor/libxml/xpointer.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/xml.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/xmljs/src/libxmljs.o
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:8:
../src/xml_document.h:11:34: error: expected class name
class XmlDocument : public node::ObjectWrap {
                                 ^
../src/xml_document.h:42:44: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8';
      did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> New(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                           v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:8:
../src/xml_document.h:43:49: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8';
      did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> FromHtml(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:8:
../src/xml_document.h:44:48: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8';
      did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> FromXml(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                               v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:8:
../src/xml_document.h:45:47: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8';
      did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> SetDtd(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                              v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:8:
../src/xml_document.h:48:45: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8';
      did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Root(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                            v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:8:
../src/xml_document.h:49:49: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8';
      did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Encoding(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:8:
../src/xml_document.h:50:48: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8';
      did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Version(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                               v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:8:
../src/xml_document.h:51:44: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8';
      did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Doc(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                           v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:8:
../src/xml_document.h:52:47: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8';
      did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Errors(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                              v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:8:
../src/xml_document.h:53:49: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8';
      did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> ToString(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:8:
../src/xml_document.h:54:49: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8';
      did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Validate(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:8:
../src/xml_document.h:30:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ref'; did you
      mean 'ref'?
        Ref();
        ^~~
        ref
../src/xml_document.h:29:10: note: 'ref' declared here
    void ref() {
         ^
../src/xml_document.h:34:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Unref'; did you
      mean 'unref'?
        Unref();
        ^~~~~
        unref
../src/xml_document.h:33:10: note: 'unref' declared here
    void unref() {
         ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:9:
../src/xml_node.h:9:30: error: expected class name
class XmlNode : public node::ObjectWrap {
                             ^
../src/xml_node.h:25:44: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8'; did
      you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Doc(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                           v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:9:
../src/xml_node.h:26:50: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8'; did
      you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Namespace(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                 v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:9:
../src/xml_node.h:27:51: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8'; did
      you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Namespaces(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                  v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:9:
../src/xml_node.h:28:47: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8'; did
      you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Parent(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                              v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/awaghma/.node-gyp/0.12.5/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 
      'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
```

fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/xmljs/src/libxmljs.o] Error 1

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/awaghma/smartphone_web/node_modules/excel/node_modules/libxmljs
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "excel"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! libxmljs@0.8.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.8.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the libxmljs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls libxmljs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Have you tried the libxmljs issues list (github?)? As the error suggests, try the package author to see if this has been encountered before.

Comment: You mention that there were 20 errors. You should also include those in your question...

Comment: what happens when you try install manually node-gyp `npm install node-gyp`. ?

Comment: node-gyp installs successfully

Comment: Have added errors part too..

Comment: Hopefully you will resolve the error, but here's an option to keep in your back pocket: if your Mac is a development machine, then you could consider using a Linux virtual machine instead. [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) is a convenient way to set up a development VM with a low footprint.